.NET C#: Бесплатная библиотека для создания отчетов в формате PDF и HTML (аналог Stimulsoft.Reports)
Стоит задача по созданию отчетов в формате PDF и HTML. Отчет представляет собой документ, в который должны подставляться различные данные из базы и других источников. Ранее использовался Stimulsoft.Reports, но он платный. А в пробной версии на все документы накладывается водяной знак "trial". Нужен бесплатный аналог. Есть ли такие? И если да, то какой лучше использовать?


Либы для pdf,
Либа pdf в html,
Либы html в pdf

Но лично у нас на предприятии очень любят всё по лицензии Apache, по этому мы используем pdfbox, есть так-же множество его открытых форков

А есть что-то чтобы сразу и html и pdf из одного шаблона?

по этому поводу не подскажу, я использовал Razer page для создания html и затем уже её просто конвертировали в pdf через библиотеку

@DeniskaSosiSka, спасибо
